# Unable to start/stop spark in Before and After methods in Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-spark, junit

I'm writing unit tests for my spark application but am running into an issue.  Ideally, I'd like to have a `Before` and `After` method where I start and stop spark (rather than doing it in the unit test method itself).

The below implementation works, I'm able to declare the `SparkConf` and the `JavaSparkContext` at the beginning of the test and then execute `sc.close()` at the end.

```
@Test
public void testMethod(){
            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("testGeoHashAggregation");
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

            // yadda yadda yadda   
            //tests here

            sc.close()
}
```

But I would like to set it up so that the start and stop have their own methods

```
@Before
public void init(){
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("testGeoHashAggregation");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
}

@After
public void close(){
    sc.close();
}
```

Any ideas why the latter doesn't work?  I will run into an exception that some object is not serializable.

Comment: the second code seems weird - I suppose `JavaSparkContext` is not only in `init()` but in class. If the problem with serialization is with some object - just `implement Serializable` interface. If you have a problem with serialization of `JavaSparkContext` add transient to this field.
something like -> 
`public class YourClass {
private transient JavaSparkContext sc;
.... all code here with Before ... After`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At first, `sc` should be a class field, not local variable of `init ()` method
2. Secondly, isn't it better to use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`? Spark start is quite long (web ui, cluster, etc. is starting each time), if full isolation is not a problem, then `@BeforeClass` would be better. However it's only an advice, not solution for your question.

So, code will look like in this example:

```
public class SomeSparkTest implements Serializable {

private static transient JavaSparkContext jsc;

@BeforeClass 
public static void init () {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("testGeoHashAggregation");
    jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
}

@AfterClass
public static void close(){
    jsc.close();
}

@Test 
public void shouldSomethingHappend () {
    // given 
    // preparation of RDDs
    JavaRDD<String> rdd = jsc.textFile(...)

    // when
    // actions
    long count = rdd.count()

    // then
    // verify output; assertThat is from FestAssertions, not necessary
    assertThat(count).isEqualTo(5)
}
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/apache/spark/JavaAPISuite.java) you've got some test suite from Spark repository

Explanation: Any lambda or inner class, that you're using in test, has reference to outer class, in this case it is the test class. Spark always serializes lambdas/inner classes, even in local cluster mode. If your test class is not serializable or if it has any non-serializable field, then such error will appear

Comment: Thanks, I had the JavaSparkContext as a class field, but not sure why I wrote it in as a local variable of init.  Anyway,  setting that to transient solved my issue.

I didnt think about `BeforeClass` vs `Before`.  Will look into that, thanks for the help!

Comment: @rvisio OK, so just add Serializable to your test class and mark JavaSparkContext as transient. Should work :)